# Storing Oauth2 Credentials in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to figure out how I can storing OAuth2 credentials in golang?

Currently I do this in Python:

from oauth2client.file import Storage
...
storage = Storage('settings.dat')

Is there anything similar in go? Does anyone have an example? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is what you need: https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/

Comment: If you are looking to simply store your *client* credentials (i.e. so your app can auth against an OAuth2 *server*), then just store them in an environmental variable or settings file (JSON is good) and use `os.GetEnv` or `encoding/json` to grab them when the application launches (use `init()`). This means that the keys are not compiled into your app and can be rotated/updated without a recompile.

Comment: @elithrar that is not what I am trying to do, thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [a CacheFile which you pass as the TokenCache](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth#CacheFile).  Here is some code ripped from a project which uses google drive with oauth2 which should hopefully get you started!

```
import "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth"

// Ask the user for a new auth
func MakeNewToken(t *oauth.Transport) error {
    if *driveAuthCode == "" {
        // Generate a URL to visit for authorization.
        authUrl := t.Config.AuthCodeURL("state")
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Go to the following link in your browser\n")
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s\n", authUrl)
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Log in, then re-run this program with the -drive-auth-code parameter\n")
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "You only need this parameter once until the drive token file has been created\n")
        return errors.New("Re-run with --drive-auth-code")
    }

    // Read the code, and exchange it for a token.
    //fmt.Printf("Enter verification code: ")
    //var code string
    //fmt.Scanln(&code)
    _, err := t.Exchange(*driveAuthCode)
    return err
}

func main() {
    // Settings for authorization.
    var driveConfig = &oauth.Config{
        ClientId:     *driveClientId,
        ClientSecret: *driveClientSecret,
        Scope:        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        RedirectURL:  "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
        AuthURL:      "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        TokenURL:     "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        TokenCache:   oauth.CacheFile(*driveTokenFile),
    }

    t := &oauth.Transport{
        Config:    driveConfig,
        Transport: http.DefaultTransport,
    }

    // Try to pull the token from the cache; if this fails, we need to get one.
    token, err := driveConfig.TokenCache.Token()
    if err != nil {
        err := MakeNewToken(t)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to authorise: %s", err)
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Does that write to a static file somewhere or is it just stored temporarily in memory?

Comment: To a file - the one specified by `*driveTokenFile`.  Have added a link to the docs.

Comment: It looks like `code.google.com/p/goauth2` has been deprecated in favor of `golang.org/x/oauth2`, but that appears to have removed `CacheFile`. I see a [ReuseTokenSource](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#ReuseTokenSource), but no example of how to use it to save credentials without forcing users through the acceptance flow each time.